# Invite users to a Facebook Canvas app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, canvas

I'm currently developing a facebook canvas app, and looking for an automated method to invite user's friends to use this app, with the old API version that is still valid till 30th of April.

I know there are apprequests, but they are sent with FB.ui, not with Graph API.

I also found /user/apprequests (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/apprequests) method, which allows to POST requests. But after I send this request, the user I'm trying to invite does not get the notification. And it also appeared that it does not work with the users who did not accept TOS (not installed the app), so this method is pretty useless.

The only way I can think of, is posting on the friends' walls, or mentioning them in user's posts.

Or are there any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

If your App is a game, use the Request Dialog. If not, use the Send Dialog. Auto-Inviting is not possible and bad practice anyway > spammy. Always let the user decide which friends he wants to invite.